# Telegram users don't receive messages from bot

Tags: java, activemq-classic, telegram-bot

I have a problem with my telegram bot. I use activeMQ to send news messages separately from chat messages (more than 100000 messages). I see that news messages successfully enqueued and dequeued from queue but none of the users receive any news. It works fine while testing (400 users) but doesn't work on production.

After sending message to Telegram I have code that analyze the response:

```
private boolean analizeResponse(List<NameValuePair> payload, HttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        boolean result = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200;
        log.info("Response status Code is: " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

        if (entity != null) {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent(), "UTF-8"));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                content.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 403 && content.toString().contains("Forbidden: bot was blocked by the user")) {
                new TelegramUserDao().unsubscribeUser(payload.stream().filter(pair -> pair.getName().equals("chat_id")).collect(Collectors.toList()).get(0).getValue());
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

and in activemq Consumer I use Client_Acknowledge session:

```
            connection = factory.createConnection();
            connection.start();
            connection.setExceptionListener(this);
            session = connection.createSession(false, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            Destination destination = session.createQueue(queueName);
            consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);
...

                result = telegramSender.sendMessage(telegramBody);
                }
                if (result) {
                    sent++;
                    message.acknowledge();
                } else {
                    noSent++;
                }
                int count = message.getIntProperty(DELIVERY_COUNT);
                if (count >= MAX_REDELIVERY) {
                    message.acknowledge();
                    log.warn("news : " + news.getId() + " isn't send to user : " + newsLetter.getUserId());
                }
```

telegramSender.sendMessage(telegramBody); method return value that I got in analizeResponse method. ActiveMQ queue decreases every second and I think that I have 200 status code from telegram or I'm wrong.

Comment: Telegram possible block you because you reach some limit, check logs for errorCode = 429,  errorMessage = "Too Many Requests: retry after <seconds to retry>

Comment: But if I got 429 errorCode than no one of users which have chat with bot don't receive any massages to?

Comment: What is the response you get from Telegram? Would you please share more specific details? log? response? do you send then once? or you do it separately with time ?

Comment: I push all messages in activemq queue by producer and then I received them in while loop by activemq consumer and send it to telegram users. If I got 200 status code I do message.acknowledge(). In activemq web console I see that queue is decreases.